# Interaction between flex and iframe

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, iframe, actionscript

I have a flex application and there is an Iframe(HTML code) inside the flex App. How do i trigger an event from Iframe and listen to it in flex app or call AS method in flex app from the JS in Iframe? I need to pass some info as well to the parent flex application.

Comment: Can you share what yo’ve tried so far? Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ExternalInterface (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) for it.

For example, to call method try:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.call("myMethod", { id: 'somedataID' } );
}
```